# Audio not Playing with Pygame Module

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I want to play audio with pygame module but it doesn't work for me. When I run code below, it just gives me this message in less than a second without any error:

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

Code:

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("/home/hermes/Desktop/test/ring_tone.wav")
mixer.music.play()
```

I have used other famous library,playsound but it didn't help me with my problem.if you know any other library for playing songs in python please tell me.

Comment: Have you tried to see if the volume is producing?  pygame.mixer.music.get_volume()  pygame.mixer.music.set_volume()

Comment: @Taku_ it doesnt do anything

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot the main event loop:

```
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init() #<-- initializes video
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("/home/hermes/Desktop/test/ring_tone.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play()


SONG_END = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(SONG_END)


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == SONG_END:
            print("the song ended!")
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

cf. https://nerdparadise.com/programming/pygame/part3

without it, pygame starts playing and immediately exits.

Comment: It raises this error:   pygame.error: video system not initialized

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use pyaudio lib. 
I play audio file with python on my github 
source code：

[I using pyaudio paly wav file](https://github.com/Willseed/Common_Method/blob/master/play.py)

and format Transfer audio/vedio file can use ffmepg